# Jquery Validation errorPlacement / submitHandler

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, plugins, errorplacement

How do I write my js so that the responses from the jquery validation plugin are placed inside the form field boxes?

The html form looks like:

```
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="POST" action="">
<p>
 <label for="cname">Name</label>
 <input id="cname" type="text" name="name" size="60" class="required" minlength="2" />
</p>
<p>
 <label for="cemail">E-Mail</label>
 <input id="cemail" type="text" name="email" size="60"  class="required email" />
</p>
<p>
 <label for="curl">URL</label>
 <input id="curl" type="text" name="url" size="60"  class="url" value="" />
</p>
<p>
 <label for="ccomment">Your comment</label>
 <textarea id="ccomment" type="text" name="comment" cols="72" rows="8"  class="required"></textarea>
</p>
<p>
 <div id="button2"><input class="submit" id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Send Email"/></div>
</p>
</form>
```

The js currently looks like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#commentForm').validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'process.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(returnedData) {
                    $('#commentForm').append(returnedData);
                }
            });         
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Whats the proper js to put the errorPlacement inside the form fields' input value? So that if someone didn't include their email the response "this field is required" will appear inside the input value for email. Currently, it is returned after the input. Thank you.

Comment: do you mean over write the values in inputs? really not clear how you want errors

Comment: Yes exactly what I mean. Thank you

Comment: really makes little sense so far. If you over write values, how does user see or edit them?

Comment: I mean if the email or name field is left blank, the js returns the response "this field is required" inside the form field as a 'focus' event. I apologize for any confusion in my wording of the issue. Thank you

Comment: not hard to do it but would take some time to code and debug the logic and integrate with plugin...afraid I can't help right now. If this is of any help have at it  http://jsfiddle.net/charlietfl/2SdFR/2/

Comment: Wish I could also say it werent hard myself, but I have been researching and hopefully will solve this issue soon. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I say not hard only dues to lots of jquery...it's not really a simple thing you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation offers the option `errorPlacement` which is a function for exactly this purpose.

I wrote this up quickly for you using jQuery UI's `position` utility (so you'd have to include jQuery UI to make my version work):

```
  //in your $.validate options, add this
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      error.insertAfter( element).position({
          my:'right top',
          at:'right top',
          of:element          
      });
   }
```

Note I also defined this CSS:

```
label.error { color: red; position:absolute; }​
```

See it in action here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/Z64Tv/

Comment: Thank you for your ideas @Ryley. how would you use jquery's position to put the validation responses inside the form's text input fields? Or at least appear that they are so by floating them over the input field? Or is this impossible? Currently, I can only get the elements to appear before or after the input fields.

Comment: sorry nick, I had the wrong jsfiddle link - check out the new link - it's working as you want there...