# Jquery ErrorPlacement conflict with Position:Absolute

Tags: jquery, css, validation, css-position, errorplacement

I am having a problem with the Ajax errorPlacement for my Validation Plugin ([See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nick_B/V8V2J/)). **ErrorPlacement** combined with **position:absolute** is forcing my ajax validation response to pop up in the wrong place.

If the user has not entered any information yet, the error messages pop up in the correct position (floated to the right side of the input field in red text). However, if the user has inputted information, then deletes it, the ajax alert ("this field is required") pops up in the wrong place in the field below where it is supposed to. To view the problem, type in all fields correctly, then delete your name. The message "this field is required" pops up in the email field, but it belongs in the name field.

The js that controls the validation is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
              error.insertAfter( element).position({
                  my:'right top',
                  at:'right top',
                  of:element          
              });
                  error.fadeOut(3000);
         }  
    }); 
});
```

The css that it is causing the problem is:

```
label.error { position:absolute;}
```

I need to include this css so that I can float the errors over the input fields. See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nick_B/V8V2J/) to see the problem. Thank you!

Comment: what's `my, at, of`?. I've never seen this in `position()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just revise your css as follows:

```
form p {
    position: relative;   /* This ensures error label is positioned within the p tag */
}
label.error {  
    top: 0; /* This ensures that it lines up with the top of the input */
    right:90px; 
    color: red; 
    position:absolute;
}
```

Even tested in IE just to be sure...

Comment: Thank you awesome so much help.

Answer (score 1):

Nick, you've missed the point (I answered your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559506/jquery-validation-errorplacement-submithandler) about this).  jQuery UI has a [Position](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/) utility.  That's what I was using to position the labels where you want them.  So the only "error" in your jsFiddle is that you didn't check the "jQuery UI" box under resources.  I made a version of your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/V8V2J/7/) where I removed the right:90px thing and checked the jQuery UI box.  That's it.

If you're wanting to change how your labels are positioned relative to the element with an error in it, check out the `offset` option in the Position utility (linked above).

Comment: Thanks @Ryley. You're right. I didnt understand the inclusion of jquery ui.

Comment: Only one other thing is unclear. Why if i include error.fadeOut() does it only fadeOut the first time? I updated the fiddle to show what I mean… Any ideas are really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: errorPlacement really only handles the "where" of the error messages, none of the other logic is there.  You might need to explore overriding how `showErrors` works, check out this SO question for details (the jsfiddle linked from there is relevant to you):  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8842099/312208